# Cocos2d - Object seems to be resetting its position

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

I have an Enemy class that gets created on a GameplayLayer at a given position. When I spawn the enemy, and then return its current position in the log, it returns the position it was created at (correctly). Now, I'm trying to add some movement to the Enemy class's update method. However, when I do that, it "teleports" the enemy to position 0,0, then applies the movement to it. When I return the enemy's position from within its update method, it reports 0,0, not the position it was spawned at.

Now, I'm using an animation to represen the enemies on screen. Can I access the animation's position the same way I would with a sprite, or am I missing something entirely?

Spawning the enemy in the gameplay layer:

```
CCLOG(@"Creating Enemy");
Enemy *enemy = [[Enemy alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"node-red-1.png"]];
[enemy setPosition:spawnLocation];
[sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:enemy z:ZValue tag:kEnemySpriteTagValue];
[enemies addObject:enemy];
```

Enemy movement action:

```
CCLOG(@"Enemy->Starting the Traveling Animation");
action = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:skullRedAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
self.moveAction = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:(screenSize.height/200) position:ccp(self.position.x, screenSize.height + 100)];
[self runAction:moveAction];
break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being in my init method, specifically the order in which I was doing some things.